# Accepts nested attributes for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

might be a simple question but i can´t get data from one form pass to another model. I am just starting so the code is real simple. I have 2 models

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :properties
end


class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :client
end
```

I am using form_for and nesting f.fields_for

```
<%= form_for(@property) do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> Descripcion:</label>
        <%= f.text_field :descripcion, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <%= f.fields_for :clients do |clients| %> 
        <%= clients.text_field :nombre %>
        <%= clients.text_field :apellido %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The form works just for one model (properties), there is no error but the data for client is just not getting to my client model.
I am guessing that the problem might be with strong parameters of the nested form but i cannot fix the problem. Here is my controller por properties:

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @properties = Property.all
    @clients = Client.all
  end

 def new
    @property = Property.new
 end

 def create
    @property=Property.new(params.require(:property).permit(:direccion, :descripcion, :piezas, :precio, :banos, :superficie_total, :pisos, :piscina, :superficie_construida, :amoblado, :estacionamiento, :bodega, :estado, :casa, :departamento, :terreno, :gastos_comunes, :comentarios, :comuna, :ciudad))

   if @property.save
     flash[:notice] = "La Propiedad ha sido creada exitosamente =)"
     redirect_to(:action => 'index')

   else
     render('new')
     flash[:error] = "Por algun motivo no pudimos crear la propiedad =("
   end
end

  def show
     @property = Property.all
  end
```

Can anybody give me some help??

Answer (score 0):

you made a couple of mistake.

**First mistake**
As mention in [Documentation NestedAttributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)  you used wrong `nested_attributes`.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :properties
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :properties
end


class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
end
```

**Second Mistake** is strong parameter. I would like to suggest you to go throw [Sitepoint rails-forms-with-nested-attributes](http://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/) would help you.